# DEFAULT keyword in mysql prepared statements

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

Is it safe and sound to use the DEFAULT keyword in mysql prepared statements like:

`INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, field3) VALUES(?, ?, DEFAULT)`

?

I have a long list of columns and I would like to use DEFAULT for those I do not provide a value so:

`INSERT INTO table VALUES (?,?,?,DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)`

instead of:

`INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8, field9, field10, field11, field12, field13, field14, field15, field16, field17, field18, field19,) VALUES (?,?,?,DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)`

(Yes, I know I can omit the columns in order to make them be filled by the default value, but I think in this case, where no column is specified, it will shift all the parameters that will substitute the ? by one or more place, making the query update the wrong fields and causing errors)

I am not so expert about the risks of NOT using a ? reference into the VALUES brackets in an insert query so I am worried I could make the prepared statement exploitable or not safe.

Comment: What makes you think it's unsafe ? You can by the way omit the default part by doing simply : `INSERT INTO table (field1, field2) VALUES(?, ?)`

Comment: Please explain what your specific concern is with using it. What do you think could go wrong, which prompted you to ask the question?

Comment: Sorry, I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Using an `INSERT INTO table VALUES` without specifying _any_ field names at all is possible, but it's widely considered to be a bad practice because a) the code is less readable, since you have to go away and look elsewhere for what columns are being changed, making debugging and maintenance harder, and b) the order of columns in a SQL table can change (they can be moved around, or columns can be added and deleted), meaning your code could easily fail silently by inserting things into the wrong columns, if you forgot to update the query code - again, it's a maintenance headache.

Comment: So the best approach is simply to omit those columns entirely from the statement. e.g. if you are happy for field4 to use its default value then do `INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, field3, field5) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)`. This is perfectly valid, and there's no way it can be used to exploit anything - again, you didn't really say how you think such a case might be exploitable??

Comment: The thing is that is an approach I know and use. The question is another: substituting a question mark with the keyword DEFAULT will make the statement exploitable?

Answer (score 1):

Using a DEFAULT value inside a prepared statement is the only way to insert a default value, since you can't bind a default value.

Consider you have a column, which has a default value but also allows NULL values:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (a INT, b INT, c INT DEFAULT 4);
```

Unless you use MariaDB (where `default` is supported in binding by using indicators), you can only insert data using DEFAULT if there is no value available for column c.

Comment: my question is: is it safe to use DEFAULT in a prepared statement?

Comment: If it would be unsafe, it wouldn't exist. Without DEFAULT it wouldn't be possible to UPDATE a table using default values (for insert it's possible to omit the column, but it doesn't help to make the code more readable and understandable).